# Is there a way to check what Style is setting a property's value for a control?

Tags: wpf, telerik, styles, rad-controls, radcombobox

Just wondering if there is any tool to see what Style is setting a property value for a control. In our application, all the RadComboBoxes have `IsEditable` property set to true. There is some DLL that we are using is causing this. I am guessing there is some `Style` without a `Key`for the RadComboBox that sets this.

In WPF Inspector, I can see that every RadComboBox control in our App has `IsEditable` set to `True`. And under the Resources section there are a bunch of resources that show up, and some of these are set inside some external DLLs that we include in our project.

I would like to know what particular Style is causing this, so that we can narrow down our problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I usually check who set the property on Telerik controls by using [Snoop](https://github.com/snoopwpf/snoopwpf).

Pin the element with Control + Shift + Mouse hover. Then select exact element in visual tree, select the suspecting Style property and use Delve button to see properties of Style property, namely look for x:Key.

When you find the key (usually RadSometingStyle or Template), open the install directory of Telerik controls, browse to Themes foleder and search over the all xaml files there. You'll find the style definition there. Good luck... :)

Comment: Thanks for suggesting snoop!

Comment: Works to find the x:Key, but mine just says "System.Windows.Controls.TextBox", so I'm guessing my style in this case is a style without an x:Key specified, which is based on another style somewhere.

Comment: @Zack You are correct, it means that the style is set via [TargetType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.targettype(v=vs.110).aspx) property. That's either a default style from default theme or overriden style if you've loaded some custom theme.